# Boto3 fails to find resources when using lambda python runtime in containerized lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, runtime, aws-sam-cli

When I try to access resources from AWS via boto3 (for example secrets from the secrets manager) I get an error when I use the python lambda runtime (public.ecr.aws/lambda/python3.8). I use the SAM CLI to deploy my function.

**This is my template file**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
    Ask-Waldo-Master-Data-Sam

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 10
    Tracing: Active
    Environment:
      Variables:
        POWERTOOLS_METRICS_NAMESPACE: "ask-waldo"
        POWERTOOLS_SERVICE_NAME: "ask-waldo-master-service"
        LOG_LEVEL: DEBUG
        STAGE: DEVELOPMENT
  Api:
     TracingEnabled: true

Resources:
    MasterDataService:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            PackageType: Image
            ImageConfig:
                Command: ["askwaldo_master_data.app.lambda_handler"]
            MemorySize: 4096
            Events:
                ApiEvent:
                    Properties:
                        RestApiId:
                            Ref: AskWaldoMasterDataService
                        Path: /{proxy+}
                        Method: ANY
                    Type: Api
            FunctionName: AskWaldoMasterDataService
            CodeUri: ./src
            Timeout: 300 # timeout of your lambda function
            MemorySize: 128 # memory size of your lambda function
            Description: Ask-Waldo Master data API serverless service
        ManagedPolicyArns:
            - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'
        Policies:
            -
                PolicyName: 'ParameterStoreParameterAccess'
                PolicyDocument:
                    Version: '2012-10-17'
                    Statement:
                    -
                        Effect: Allow
                        Action:
                        - 'ssm:GetParameter*'
                        Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter/dev/parameterStoreBlog*'

        Metadata:
            Dockerfile: Dockerfile
            DockerContext: ./src
            DockerTag: v1
            

    AskWaldoMasterDataService:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
        Properties:
            StageName: prod
            OpenApiVersion: '3.0.0'

    LambdaFunctionLogGroup:
        Type: "AWS::Logs::LogGroup"
        DependsOn: "MasterDataService"
        Properties: 
            RetentionInDays: 30
            LogGroupName: !Join ["", ["/aws/lambda/", !Ref MasterDataService]]
```

**This is my Dockerfile:**

```
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/var/task/"
ARG APP_DIR="${FUNCTION_DIR}/askwaldo_master_data"
ARG RUNTIME_VERSION="3.8"
ARG DISTRO_VERSION="3.12"


# Stage 2 - build function and dependencies
FROM python:${RUNTIME_VERSION} AS build-image

ARG FUNCTION_DIR
ARG RUNTIME_VERSION
ARG APP_DIR
# Create function directory
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_DIR}
# Copy requirements
COPY askwaldo_master_data/requirements.txt ${APP_DIR}
# Optional – Install the function's dependencies
RUN pip install -r ${APP_DIR}/requirements.txt --target ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY askwaldo_master_data ${APP_DIR}


# Stage 3 - final runtime image
# Grab a fresh copy of the Python image
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:${RUNTIME_VERSION}
# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
# Set working directory to function root directory
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}
# Copy in the built dependencies
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}

CMD ["askwaldo_master_data.app.lambda_handler"]
```

When I run the code locally without lambda I get no errors. Also when I run the code in the normal python environment (not the aws runtime) I get no errors. Only when I try to use the lambda environment from AWS I get the following error when starting the local api via the sam cli: Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.

```
[WARNING]       2021-09-24T08:53:20.615Z                Subsegment secretsmanager discarded due to Lambda worker still initializing
[WARNING]       2021-09-24T08:53:20.828Z                No subsegment to end.
```

Could someone help me to figure out why boto3 is not able to access the resources when being executed within a container?

Comment: Since it says still initialising, can you add a delay before calling?

Comment: I already tried that, but no luck... I've now got rid of the warnings but still I don't receive the secrets. I'm wondering if it might be related to my aws configuration within the docker container. But I don't understand that I don't get an authentication error.